# slider data isn't working fine in bootstrap with backend data

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, ejs

Hello m showing data from backend into a slider but its not responding well, initially it was like this 
[image]

and sliding left but now its like this

[image]

all of its data is showing at once. I want to show other data at next slide 
I'm using this slider

> https://codepen.io/kravisingh/pen/pLGzgo

code:

```
  <div class="carousel-item active">
       <% meetings.forEach(function(meeting){ %>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 upcoming-btn">
                      <span href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg dashboard-icon" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                          <p style="padding-top: 15px; font-size: 25px;
                                                        font-weight: bold;"><%= meeting.subject %></p>
                          <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"><%= convertDate(meeting.date) %></p>
                          <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Upcoming</p>
                        </span>
                     </div> 
                   </div> 
                 <% }) %>   
               </div>
```

complete slider code:

```css
.col-md-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

.col-md-3 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body .carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: red;
}

body .carousel-control-prev-icon,
body .carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-color: red;
}

body .no-padding {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet HERE and posted the images too. We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **The only one reason**, why you get all data in your slider, it's because there's no condition. If you look at the sliders, there's have a parent as `active` class and in the `active` class, have a child. You've to mapping it.

‍ **Before we go to the slider,** the first one you've to do is change your `meetings` list object.

You can use this code below  to change your `meetings` list object structure, so your `meetings` list will have a parent and child:

```js
function setMeetingSliders(meetings) {
  let i = 0;
  const meetingsTemp = [];

  let itemPerSlider = 4;

  meetings.forEach((meeting, index) => {
    if(index%itemPerSlider === 0) {
      meetingsTemp[i] = [];
      meetingsTemp[i].push(meeting);
      i++;
    } else {
      meetingsTemp[i-1].push(meeting);
    }
  });

  return meetingsTemp;
};
```

⏱ **Now**, before your render your `meetings` list, **make sure to use this function to change your `meetings` list object**. For an example, you can look at this code below:

```js
app.get('/yourmeetings', (req, res) => {
  let meetings = GetMeetingFromDatabase();

  // change your meetings list obect
  meetings = setMeetingSliders(meetings);

  res.render('meetings', { meetings });

});
```

‍ After you change your `meetings` list object, now you can use this sliders below to make your sliders works.

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
    <!-- mapping your meetings parent -->
    <% meetings.forEach(function(meeting,index){ %>
    <div class="carousel-item <%= index === 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
      <!-- mapping your meetings child -->
      <% meeting.forEach(function(m){ %>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 upcoming-btn">
          <span href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg dashboard-icon" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
            <p style="padding-top: 15px; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"><%= m.subject %></p>
            <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"><%= convertDate(m.date) %></p>
            <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Upcoming</p>
          </span>
        </div> 
      </div>    
      <% }) %>   
    </div>
  <% }) %>   
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I hope it can help you .

Comment: eeting.ejs:231 229| <div class="carousel-item <%= index === 0 ? 'active' : '' %>"> 230| <!-- mapping your meetings child --> >> 231| <% meeting.forEach(function(m){ %> 232| <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3"> 233| <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 upcoming-btn"> 234| <span href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg dashboard-icon" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"> meeting.forEach is not a function

Comment: make sure to use `serMeetingsSlider` above.

Comment: in ejs where i have to use setMeetingSliders

Answer (score 0):

Place the s near the end of your pages, right before the closing  tag, to enable them and then use this:

```html
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                   <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg"  class="img-fluid">
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                   <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg"  class="img-fluid">
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                   <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg"  class="img-fluid">
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                   <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg"  class="img-fluid">
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                   <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg" class="img-fluid">
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                   <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg" class="img-fluid">
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                   <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg" class="img-fluid">
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                   <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg" class="img-fluid">
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg"  class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg"  class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg"  class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-sleeping-disorders-as-a-reason-for-insomnia-293777093.jpg"  class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```